# What does the term reusable components means in angular/react/vue?

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js

I have hear a lot of the term "reusable components". what this is mean?

For example I want to display common user details (such id, name, age, etc.).

Did it mean component "plug and play", just to write the selector say `<user-preview>` and the component should do the logic such fetch the data from the server and display it?

or just a an simple html and the fields are bind using parent component?

Comment: You can get built in component from somewhere or you can build your own component using html like elements and html elements also. You can keep the logic there or spearate. Ex: YOu can create a <NavBar> component and you can reuse that for every page.

Comment: Do some quick searches on [npmjs.com](http://www.npmjs.com) for things like "vue checkbox" or "react color picker".  That should give you a good idea of what components can potentially look like.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, a component can act as an individual entity, and can be implemented wherever you please in the application. This is further enhanced through inputs (props) and outputs (Angular's EventEmitter outputs).

If you created a 'Back to Top' button component, such that it functioned independently of any other component in the application, that component is then 'Plug and Play'.

A good example would be **Angular Material** -- wherein you use Angular component to style your application (e.g. `<mat-toolbar></mat-toolbar>`)

Answer (score 0):

2 types of reusable components:

- UI component (a card, a button, layout for example), allows to have a template of an element usable everywhere in your app. Its content will be injected via the outside (a parent for example).
- a reusable component with a business logic but it is necessary to be sure that  these data will be the same wherever the component is used.

Answer (score 0):

The term *reusable component* is not specific to JS frameworks. The word *reusable* is not even important here. Every frontend framework has some kind of Component even if it calls it differently (e.g. widget, view etc.).

What is a *Component*?

A *Component* is just a specific part of your UI that you decide to wrap into a separate unit. Usually a component has an external input (e.g. properties in React, attributes in Angular) which setups the component for a specific use case. Also, there is usually a way to pass data out of the component (e.g. `onClick`).

A component can be a button, a label with a specific color, or something entirely complex. It's common to compose complex components from simple components. For example, every React application is just one big component.

What is inside a component is entirely up to you. A component does not have to be reusable, it can be also used only once. It can be a smart component (e.g. calling backend services) or it can be just a dumb/layout component (a component that only adds colors, fonts, styles to a simple functionality).

The concept of a component is very similar to the concept of a *class* in Objective Oriented Programming, the main principle is *encapsulation*. A component encapsulates some part of UI functionality and makes it easier to build complex UI.